# I am getting 403 forbidden error while accessing cacti from the browser

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, cacti, snmpd

I can't access cacti from my browser although I have configured the cacti.conf file and also my cacti directory permission is 755. I have disabled selinux as well but still, I can't access cacti from my browser such as http://ip/cacti

```
*#
# Cacti: An rrd based graphing tool
#
# For security reasons, the Cacti web interface is accessible only to
# localhost in the default configuration. If you want to allow other clients
# to access your Cacti installation, change the httpd ACLs below.
# For example:
# On httpd 2.4, change "Require host localhost" to "Require all granted".
# On httpd 2.2, change "Allow from localhost" to "Allow from all".
Alias /cacti    /usr/share/cacti
<Directory /usr/share/cacti/>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                # httpd 2.4
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                # httpd 2.2
                Order allow,deny
                Deny from all
                Allow from all
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/cacti/install>
        # mod_security overrides.
        # Uncomment these if you use mod_security.
        # allow POST of application/x-www-form-urlencoded during install
        #SecRuleRemoveById 960010
        # permit the specification of the rrdtool paths during install
        #SecRuleRemoveById 900011
</Directory>
# These sections marked "Require all denied" (or "Deny from all")
# should not be modified.
# These are in place in order to harden Cacti.
<Directory /usr/share/cacti/log>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/cacti/rra>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </IfModule>
</Directory>*
```